# java.lang.NumberFormatException error after inputting a number

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling

I am feeling quite stupid at this point for not being able to figure out something that is most likely a simple fix. I keep getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at searchSorting.main(searchSorting.java:15)" after inputting how many numbers I want to input. Others solutions to this problem just don't seem to apply to me somehow. Thanks for the help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class searchSorting 
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        String line;
        int number, search, item, array[], first, last, middle;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");
        number = in.nextInt();
        array = new int [number];

        item = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        double[] values = new double[item];

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("Input number " + i + ": ");
    values[i] = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
}
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    System.out.print(values[index] + "  ");
    in.nextLine();
    Arrays.sort(values);
    System.out.println("Sorted number is: " + Arrays.toString(values));


System.out.println("Enter the number you are looking for?");
      search = in.nextInt();
      first = 0;
      last = (item - 1);
      middle = (first + last)/2;

      while( first <= last )
      {
         if ( array[middle] < item )
           first = middle + 1;
         else if ( array[middle] == item )
         {
           System.out.println(item + " found at location " + (middle + 1) + ".");
           break;
         }
         else
         {
             last = middle - 1;
         }
         middle = (first + last)/2;
      }
      if ( first > last )
          System.out.println(item + " is not found.\n");
   
}}
```

Comment: Why use `item = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());` instead of the more direct `item = in.nextInt();`?

Comment: I did this but now my Input Number 0: is  no longer printing after it

Answer (score 0):

You call this:

```
 number = in.nextInt();
```

Assuming the user types 123 and ENTER, this call consumes the 123 and leaves the input stream positioned before the end-of-line character.

The next relevant code is

```
item = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

The nextLine call advances the input stream past the end-of-line, returning all characters it passed on the way.  Since the ENTER key was pressed immediately after 123, the returned value is the emoty string. Which is not an integer.

You need to review your strategy of sometimes scanning numbers (nextInt) and sometimes scanning rest-of-linr (nextLine).  Mixing the two needs to be done quite carefully.  You might be better advised to stick to the numerical methods (nextInt/nextDouble).

For example, replacing this

```
 item = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

by this

```
 item = in.nextInt();
```

automatically handles the line-ending.

---

From discussion in comments:

> I am still confused as to why it's having me input
> the value a second time on the next line

Making assumptions about how you modified the code since your initial question: it's because you've written code that reads the number twice:

```
    System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");
    number = in.nextInt();    // **** first input ****
    array = new int [number]; 

    item = in.nextDouble();   // **** second input ****
    double[] values = new double[item];
```

Each time you call for `in.nextSomething()` the Scanner is going to read more input.  It should likely just be this:

```
    System.out.print("How many numbers you want to input?: ");  
    number = in.nextInt();  
    array = new int [number];
    double[] values = new double[number];
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanation! This solved the error issue, but now 'Input number 0:' is no longer showing up on the next line.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I don't use Scanner, but rather BufferedReader.

Comment: Certainlly, if I want a line-oriented UI as many users seem to expect (so: prompt, and then read that input, repeatedly), then I would be reading by lines and parsing the line.  From many beginner postings in SO, the concept of scanning by tokens is hard to grasp.  It's superficially attractive but has traps for the unwary.

Comment: @kayaruth - what do you mean by 'not showing up on the next line' -- after what?  Your code initially prompts for 'how many numbers?', expects to read **2 values** ('number', and 'item'), and then falls into the loop where it prompts for 'Input number N'.  So - are you typing 2 numbers after the first prompt?

Comment: This array `array = new int [number];` appears to be unused, so maybe it and the preceding read of `number` should not be there at all?

Comment: I tried getting rid of array = new int [number] but it won't build since it defines the array that's in the search. And yes it has me put two number values instead of just one

Comment: The search isn't going to work, then, since nothing is ever placed in 'array'.  I would guess it should be searching in 'values'.

Comment: I am still confused as to why it's having me input the value a second time on the next line.

Comment: updated answer (see the end) because the formatting is too complicated for a comment

Answer (score 0):

For more info check out [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) documentation, it's an excellent resource.

Edit: Try removing line 15 and replacing `item` with `number` in the next line